# Amplify - NextJS - Access lambda logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

In the AWS Amplify dashboard I can't see a way to access my /api/* route logs after deploying a hello world NextJS application. Where would these be located?

Steps:

1. init extremely simple helloworld nextjs application with
   /api/hello.js  `export default (_, res) => res.send("hello world")`
2. Deploy to amplify
3. /api/hello returns "hello world"

Can't find the logs for this lambda function nor find it anywhere in AWS or the Amplify dashboard. Even after enabling "Amplify Studio" I can't see it listed under 'Functions' but obviously I can call the endpoint without enabling Amplify Studio at all.

I can see a handler for /api/* in cloudfront distribution but can't find where the handler is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once is deployed with Amplify, go to the build page and look in the `Deploy` tab. You will find a row that says `[INFO]: - API Lambda@Edge: xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx`. The ID you see will be needed to identify the logs inside `AWS CloudWatch`.

The logs can be found going to `CloudWatch` -> `Log groups` and then you can find the API logs following this pattern: `/aws/lambda/<region: this will probably be 'us-east-1'>.xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx`

Comment: Legend haven't verified but this looks like it would be correct

Comment: This answer is outdated. See @manncito's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Amplify now provides an easy shortcut to go straight to the cloudwatch logs:

- Under app settings in amplify click monitoring
- Then select the hosting compute logs tab
- Then you will have a link for logs for each branch you have deployed

[image]